# Swift App: User selects playlist and then fills in buttons with each song?

Tags: swift, button, media-player, playlists

I'm trying to create a mediaplayer app.  I was wondering if there is a way, and how would that look, to program the app so that a user can select a playlist from their own library and those songs from the playlist would be added to various buttons.  For example, a user selects a playlist that has 10 songs.  Those 10 songs would then would be assigned to 10 separate buttons, not a tableview, so that a user can tap the button to play a selected song from that playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Apple Music library, than it will not work because Apple does not allow any manipulations with data (licensed songs) in their apps. But if you create a library of songs downloaded from somewhere inside of your app, then you can easily do it, but you should expand on that in a different post.